# Convert n-dimensional numpy array to 2-dimensional index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to convert an n-dimensional numpy array such as this one:

```
[ [ a, b, c],
  [ d, e, f] ]
```

to a 2-dimensional array of `axis_0_index`, `axis_1_index`, `cell_value`.

```
[ [ 0, 0, a],
  [ 0, 1, b],
  [ 0, 2, c],
  [ 1, 0, d],
  [ 1, 1, e],
  [ 1, 2, f] ]
```

Is this possible to do easily in NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (abuse?) `np.where` to get all the indices of the array, using an array of ones of the same shape as condition, then stack those indices with the (flattened) array and finally transpose.

```
>>> A = np.array([ [ 'a', 'b', 'c'], [ 'd', 'e', 'f'] ])
>>> ones = np.ones(A.shape)
>>> np.vstack(np.where(ones) + (A.ravel(),)).transpose()
array([['0', '0', 'a'],
       ['0', '1', 'b'],
       ['0', '2', 'c'],
       ['1', '0', 'd'],
       ['1', '1', 'e'],
       ['1', '2', 'f']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

---

After some more searching, its probably cleaner to use `np.indices`:

```
>>> X, Y = np.indices(A.shape)
>>> np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), A.ravel())).T
```

or

```
>>> np.vstack((X, Y, A)).reshape(3,A.size).T
```

The result, in both cases, is the same as above.

---

I did some timing analysis using IPython's `%timeit`. Curiously, my first solution with `where` seems to be fastest, at least for this very small test array:

```
>>> %timeit f1() # using ones and np.where
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.3 us per loop
>>> %timeit f2() # using np.indices and ravel
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 us per loop
>>> %timeit f3() # using np.indices and reshape
10000 loops, best of 3: 110 us per loop
>>> %timeit g() # using meshgrid
10000 loops, best of 3: 134 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) as shown in the sample run below -

```
In [19]: A
Out[19]: 
array([[19, 80, 63],
       [24, 54, 44]])

In [20]: m,n = A.shape

In [21]: R,C = np.meshgrid(np.arange(m),np.arange(n))

In [22]: np.column_stack((R.ravel('F'),C.ravel('F'),A.ravel()))
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0,  0, 19],
       [ 0,  1, 80],
       [ 0,  2, 63],
       [ 1,  0, 24],
       [ 1,  1, 54],
       [ 1,  2, 44]])
```